# Get text between parenthesis of a Column in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below

```
+-----+-------+------------------+--------------------------+
| ID  | Name  | Designation      | Location                 |
+-----+-------+------------------+--------------------------+
| 101 | John  | Technical Lead   | United States (New York) |
+-----+-------+------------------+--------------------------+
| 102 | Benny | Sales Manager    | India (Delhi)            |
+-----+-------+------------------+--------------------------+
| 103 | Vasu  | System Admin     | Japan (Tokyo)            |
+-----+-------+------------------+--------------------------+
| 104 | Dany  | Business Analyst | Australia (Melbourne)    |
+-----+-------+------------------+--------------------------+
```

Now I have to extract only the city from Location and keep as separate column.

Expected output

```
+-----+-------+------------------+--------------------------+-----------+
| ID  | Name  | Designation      | Location                 | City      |
+-----+-------+------------------+--------------------------+-----------+
| 101 | John  | Technical Lead   | United States (New York) | New York  |
+-----+-------+------------------+--------------------------+-----------+
| 102 | Benny | Sales Manager    | India (Delhi)            | Delhi     |
+-----+-------+------------------+--------------------------+-----------+
| 103 | Vasu  | System Admin     | Japan (Tokyo)            | Tokyo     |
+-----+-------+------------------+--------------------------+-----------+
| 104 | Dany  | Business Analyst | Australia (Melbourne)    | Melbourne |
+-----+-------+------------------+--------------------------+-----------+
```

I have tried the below but getting error `'Series' object has no attribute 'find'`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = read_excel('myfile.xlsx')
df['city'] = df.apply(lambda st: st[st.find("(")+1:st.find(")")])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with match values between `()`:

```
df["city"] = df["Location"].str.extract(r"\((.*?)\)" , expand=False)
print (df)
    ID   Name       Designation                  Location       city
0  101   John    Technical Lead  United States (New York)   New York
1  102  Benny     Sales Manager             India (Delhi)      Delhi
2  103   Vasu      System Admin             Japan (Tokyo)      Tokyo
3  104   Dany  Business Analyst     Australia (Melbourne)  Melbourne
```